# UISplitViewController should be root, so how to "push" the real starting view on top?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

My app design is very simple, at least with respect to describing the intended user-facing views:

The starting view is initially empty. Pressing a "Select" button in the navigation bar transitions to a split view. On the left (master) are the photo albums on the device. On the right (detail) are the images in a given album. The user can select up to 6 images across all albums. Pressing a "Done" button in the navigation bar transitions back to the starting view, which now displays the selected images in a grid. And that's it.

In my head, this should be as simple as embedding the starting view in a navigation controller and adding a segue from the "Select" button to the split view. But of course, it doesn't work that way. According to the Apple docs:

> Although it is possible to install a split view controller as a child
>   in some other container view controllers, doing is not recommended in
>   most cases. Split view controllers are normally installed at the root
>   of your app’s window.

If at all possible, I would like to retain my user-facing design without any shady business. I strongly suspect that there are one or more "sanctioned" ways to accomplish what I want, but I am too inexperienced with iOS development to know what they might be. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to pass back to the starting view controller the array of images, than why not just declare a protocol in the Split ViewController that the starting controller can adopt?

Comment: I don't understand you, but I think you don't understand me either. :)

Comment: Didn't mean to post previous comment as is. In any event, I think I will just ditch split view in favour of a sequence two list views and keep moving forward.